# In tcsh, how can I keep '{' '}' in assigning a variable?

Tags: tcsh, csh

I am making a simple shell script using the `tcsh` shell.
I assigned a variable as a command to use later.
But brackets within single quotes disappear.

```
set aaa = "test '10' '{}' ' " ; echo $aaa
```

Result shows

```
test '10' '' '
```

Why does this happen?
If I use `{}` and `''` separately, it is ok.

```
set aaa = "test '10' {} '' ' " ; echo $aaa
test '10' {} '' '
```

Comment: Try `echo "$aaa"`. I can't explain it, but it looks like tcsh is doing filename expansion after the variable substutution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has something to do with csh doing brace expansion after parameter expansion. It does leave `{}` by itself alone, but it seems to remove the `{}` from e.g. `foo{}`. (I don't know why it doesn't just turn that into the empty string, even though there's basically an empty list between the braces. I think in other shells `{}` or `{foo}` with just one item inside doesn't trigger brace expansion.)

Quote the expansion to avoid that.

```
> set a = 'foo{a,b}'
> echo $a
fooa foob
> set b = '{}'
> echo $b
{}
> set c = 'foo{}'
> echo $c
foo
> echo "$c"
foo{}
```

And your particular case:

```
> set aaa = "test '10' '{}' ' "
> echo "$aaa"  
test '10' '{}' '
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine. But  I have another problem.  Actually I want to set the variable, aaa, using `` command. It's the example. set aaa = ` echo "test '10' '{}'" ` .  In this case, the "" method can't use. I obtain and set the command from the pre-defined file. It has a lot of command like "awk". How can I resolve in this case?

Comment: @aroman, dealing with the quoting hell with backticks in csh seems a different question which you might want to ask separately. (Or just change to a saner shell.)